# Same task scheduled multiple times in Celery Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, celery

When I use the command to get list of scheduled Celery tasks: `celery -A project_name inspect scheduled` I see some tasks (with same task_ids, name, and ETAs) more than once in the output.. Does this mean that they will be executed multiple times? Or are they just showing up multiple times because celery runs 4 workers by default?

Examples of the same task showing up twice:

```
    {u'priority': 6, u'eta': u'2015-12-26T13:53:11.351966+00:00', u'request': {u'args': u"[195, 741, u'send_swatch', 4]", u'time_start': None, u'nam
e': u'loom.tasks.setup_celery_notifications', u'delivery_info': {u'priority': 0, u'redelivered': None, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celer
y'}, u'hostname': u'celery@947720f0ada9', u'acknowledged': False, u'kwargs': u'{}', u'id': u'ef843ab9-974a-4fff-abae-59e42a9ebb79', u'worker_pid': Non
e}}                                                                                                                                                   
     {u'priority': 6, u'eta': u'2015-12-26T13:53:11.351966+00:00', u'request': {u'args': u"[195, 741, u'send_swatch', 4]", u'time_start': None, u'nam
e': u'loom.tasks.setup_celery_notifications', u'delivery_info': {u'priority': 0, u'redelivered': None, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celer
y'}, u'hostname': u'celery@947720f0ada9', u'acknowledged': False, u'kwargs': u'{}', u'id': u'ef843ab9-974a-4fff-abae-59e42a9ebb79', u'worker_pid': Non
e}}
```

PS: I'll come to know either way at the task's ETA... but wanted to know beforehand, if possible, because this task should NOT be executed twice.